# Should I use enums for things that are named after integers?

Tags: c++, enums, coding-style

```
enum D6value {
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3,
    four = 4,
    five = 5,
    six = 6 };

bool IsCriticalHit(D6value roll);
```

I like this because it makes for better documentation on the function parameter.

I dislike this because it's something that I just dreamed up and it makes me feel clever--which is usually how I feel immediately before regretting something.

Is this bad style?

Comment: Yes, it is bad style.  It becomes atrocious if you find yourself needing to redefine `enum { six = 17 }` because the rules have changed and what was named `six` now needs to be using `17`, but there are too many things to change the `six` into `seventeen`.  (Granted, six-sided dice don't change often, but in a more general case, don't do it like this.)

Comment: No way!! what if the integer is more than 10(like 16) OR what if it's negative (-24)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the caller's likely to have a value (whether hard-coded or run-time variable) of type `D6Value` to use when calling `IsCriticalHit`, then you effectively get compile-time enforcement of correctness of the function parameter: not that you can't hack around it and pass an out-of-range value, but you're unlikely to do it accidentally.  That's potentially worthwhile.

Countering that, it callers have `int`s they want to pass in, then they'll have the inconvenience of casting them to `D6Value`, which will work whether or not the `int` is in the `1` to `6` range.  If `IsCriticalHit` forgoes defensive coding (checking roll is in range) due to a naive expectation that the `enum`s always enforcing correctness, then your worse off than if you'd used `int`s and defensive coding practices.  It's also verbose and an extra thing for other developers to get their head around.

You should also think about the set of operations you'll want to perform on `D6Value` objects: with your enum, some operators won't be provided (e.g. `+=(D6Value)`) and operations like `+` produce results that may not be in the type-implied `one`..`six` range (and pre-C++11, may wrap if the implementation chooses a representation with too few bits; C++11 defaults to `int` as the underlying type).